# Connecting and writing to multiple peripherals with one CBManager

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to make an iOS application that uses the CoreBluetooth library to start/stop and transfer the data from multiple inertial measurement units that are equipped with HM-10 BLE 4.0 modules. I have no issue connecting/writing/reading from only one module but I am not able to obtain a connection to more than one. What do I need to do to be able to do this?

I've tried to create multiple CBManagers with no luck, and I've just tried to connect to multiple peripherals by clicking one single row in my table by using,

```
for peripheral in peripherals
{
CBManager.connect(myPeripheral)
}
```

These options haven't worked and I was hoping I could get some guidance on what to try next. I am pretty new to Swift and have just picked it up in the past couple of weeks.

Here's what I have for when I search for Bluetooth Connections:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ScanTableViewController: UITableViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    var peripherals:[CBPeripheral] = []
    var manager:CBCentralManager? = nil
    var parentView:MainViewController? = nil

    //This is my tableView where I try to connect to all the peripherals
    // that come back in the table by just selecting one peripheral. 
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        for peripheral in peripherals{
            manager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    // CBCentralManagerDelegate Methods

    // I think this is where I'm having issues, how do I pass all the connected peripherals on to the next view?
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

        //pass reference to connected peripheral to parent view
        parentView?.mainPeripheral = peripheral
        peripheral.delegate = parentView
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

        //set the manager's delegate view to parent so it can call relevant disconnect methods
        manager?.delegate = parentView
        parentView?.customiseNavigationBar()

        if let navController = self.navigationController {
            navController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }

        print("Connected to " +  peripheral.name!)
    }
}
```

Here's my class that uses the Connection:

```
// MainViewController.swift
//Bo Heyse

import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var manager:CBCentralManager? = nil
    var mainPeripheral:CBPeripheral? = nil
    var mainCharacteristic:CBCharacteristic? = nil

    let BLEService = "FFE0"
    let BLECharacteristic = "FFE1"

    @IBOutlet weak var recievedMessageText: UILabel!


    //how do I get this function to send a connection to all the peripherals?
    @IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let helloWorld = "Hello World!"
        let dataToSend = helloWorld.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        if (mainPeripheral != nil) {
            mainPeripheral?.writeValue(dataToSend!, for: mainCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
        } else {
            print("haven't discovered device yet")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - CBCentralManagerDelegate Methods    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        mainPeripheral = nil
        customiseNavigationBar()
        print("Disconnected" + peripheral.name!)
    }


    // MARK: CBPeripheralDelegate Methods
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {

        for service in peripheral.services! {

            print("Service found with UUID: " + service.uuid.uuidString)

            //device information service
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }

            //GAP (Generic Access Profile) for Device Name
            // This replaces the deprecated CBUUIDGenericAccessProfileString
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }

            //Bluno Service
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == BLEService) {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }

        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        //get device name
        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "1800") {

            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A00") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found Device Name Characteristic")
                }

            }

        }

        if (service.uuid.uuidString == "180A") {

            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A29") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found a Device Manufacturer Name Characteristic")
                } else if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A23") {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    print("Found System ID")
                }

            }

        }

        if (service.uuid.uuidString == BLEService) {

            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {

                if (characteristic.uuid.uuidString == BLECharacteristic) {
                    //we'll save the reference, we need it to write data
                    mainCharacteristic = characteristic

                    //Set Notify is useful to read incoming data async
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                    print("Found Bluno Data Characteristic")
                }

            }

        }

    }
```

With the current code I've posted I get an error that returns

```
API MISUSE: Forcing disconnection of unused peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x280ab4000, 
identifier = B5835D05-CE72-D9EC-1526-2967566810F1, name = HEAD, 
state = connected>. Did you forget to cancel the connection?
```

Can anybody provide some Guidance on this issue? It is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your changes of getting a helpful answer for this question are small. There is too much code, it's mixed with irrelevant UI code, you provide two variants (connecting in a loop, connecting in a UITableView delegate) and mix the descriptions etc. Please improve your question. Create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: When a row is selected, you connect to all peripherals, not just the one in that row, Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can see the problem. After you connect to the first peripheral, you pop the current View Controller from the Navigation Controller. By doing so, your peripherals array would be released since the Controller is no longer available. Therefore, there is no reference to current discovered peripherals. When there is no reference to a peripheral, it will be disconnected. (Think of closing an app that is connected to a peripheral will force a disconnection).

#### Solution:

Instead of setting the parentView as peripheral delegate, set self (`ScanTableViewController`) as delegate and do not pop the Controller. In other words, do something that will keep the reference.